# PSTricks, how to move and rescale a picture

Tags: beamer, pstricks

How can I scale and change position of a PSTricks picture on a beamer slide?

I draw a picture and save it in tex format using Inkscale.

This is an example of the beginning of the picure

```
%LaTeX with PSTricks extensions
%%Creator: inkscape 0.48.2
%%Please note this file requires PSTricks extensions
\psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}                                        
\begin{pspicture}(453.54330444,340.1574707)
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{1 1 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(86.07989999,190.82162153)
\lineto(93
```

Comment: Could you please include a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a little ambiguous in its present form. You can use `\resizebox` to scale your `pspicture` and then `\put` together with the `picture` environment to place it at a precise location (I boxed the picture in my example just to easily reuse it):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{multido}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{%
\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
\psaxes{->}(6,6)
\psplot[linewidth=1.5pt]{0}{6}{x dup mul 6 div}
\multido{\iA=1+1}{5}{%
  \psplot[arrows=->,arrowscale=2.5]{0}{\iA}{x dup mul 6 div}}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{picture}(100,100)
\put(0,0){\resizebox{2cm}{4cm}{\usebox\mybox}}
\put(100,60){\resizebox{6cm}{2cm}{\usebox\mybox}}
\put(140,-60){\resizebox{3cm}{3cm}{\usebox\mybox}}
\end{picture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use figure environment?

Comment: @msh why use figure in `beamer`?

Comment: (I don't know, I always used it, what better to use?)

Comment: @msh Depends. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I have read about picture environment, It is totaly good =)

Comment: It is enough to load [`pstricks-add`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks) instead of [`multido`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/multido) and `pst-all`, and if [`lmodern`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lmodern) is loaded, one gets rit of the warnings. To sum up: `\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}`. `:)`